# cloudscraper issue (cloud flare version 2) in scraping website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the cloudscraper library (https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) to collect webpages. It was working correctly until recently I cannot use the library to download pages of a website.

```
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
scraper.run(...)
```

I am receiving the following error:

> cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a
> Cloudflare version 2 challenge, This feature is not available in the
> opensource (free) version.

Does anyone know how to bypass this checking?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SajjadZaidi not yet... The exception message says the feature is not available in the open-source version. Did you see any other version (non-free)?

Comment: I could not find any other version or its payment plan anywhere

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768082/cloudflare-preventing-extracting-webpage-html this seems working for me

Comment: @MuhammadAsaduzzaman, the url no longer working, what seems to work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can not bypass it, would be a cost to solve it as it needs to solve more complex captchas and other stuff, so no one is offering that for free.

DM the owner on Discord and ask for the premium plan: VeNoMouSNZ#5979

Comment: do you know the discord group he belongs to?

Comment: I've never heard of a group managed by himself, although there's an API provider group based on his code.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of the API group?

Answer (score -1):

You can reach out to the author on discord, and he does have a paid version.

Comment: Which discord?? I can't find this info anywhere.

Comment: same I can't find him either